# terminology to differentiate data that represents "ending value" versus "amount contributed"

Tags: time-series, terminology

Very broadly speaking, and particularly in Finance and timeseries data, there seems to be two kinds of factual data:

1. Data which represents the amount-to-date.  For example:  As of today, we have 50 employees.
2. Data which represents the delta or contribution for the time period in question.  For example:  over the past quarter we added 10 employees.

New datapoints can be generated that convert #1 to #2 and vice versa.  So:

1. the total number of employees working today is the sum of the employees who have been hired on all days in the past.
2. The number of employees hired/fired this quarter is the total number of employees this quarter minus the total number of employees last quarter.

I'm trying to find good vocabulary/terms to identify #1 and #2 as distinct concepts.  I also need language to describe the umbrella for both.

Right now I call #1 "point-in-time" data.  I call #2 "additive" data.  And I refer to the umbrella as "additivization."  I'm not happy with any of these.

Comment: Many data makes no reference at all to time, so your list is hardly complete. Otherwise the terminology of **stocks** and **flows** is common across several fields. In some sciences, the talk is of storages and fluxes.  Also, anything that varies in time can just be called a **time series**. I think that's broad enough to cover continuous and discrete time and continuous and discrete measurements, counts or even categories.